# Error in JitCompiler when using ng-bootstrap with angular 13

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap-modal

I'm updating angular to a newer version. I now have Angular 13 with bootstrap 5 and am using "@ng-bootstrap" version 12. However since I upgraded ng-bootstrap I get the following error.

*compiler.mjs:5700 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'visitExpression')
at compiler.mjs:5700:1
at Array.forEach ()
at JitEmitterVisitor.visitLocalizedString (compiler.mjs:5698:1)
at LocalizedString.visitExpression (compiler.mjs:1731:1)*

The error is caused by an expression in the template of the ngbCarouselComponent. I do not use the carouselComponent but only the ngmModal from ng-bootstrap.
The expression causing the problem is th i18n statement on line 107 of [this file](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/carousel/carousel.ts)

I have setup a [stackblitz with a similar configuration](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular13-bootstrap-fqwrjq), but this works fine.

I cannot see what is causing the error or how to fix this.